# How to make a list of pairwise vectors in R?

Tags: r, list

I have two types of data that I want to do a pairwise comparison on: the shams (controls) and the measurements,

```
sham1 <- c('Sham1.r1', 'Sham1.r2', 'Sham1.r3')
sham2 <- c('Sham2.r1', 'Sham2.r2', 'Sham2.r3')
shams <- list(sham1, sham2)
day14 <- c('T14d.r1', 'T14d.r2', 'T14d.r3')
day90 <- c('T90d.r1', 'T90d.r2', 'T90d.r3')
measurements <- list(hour4, day1, day3, day7, day14, day90)
```

I would like to get the following:

```
(('Sham1.r1', 'Sham1.r2', 'Sham1.r3'), ('T14d.r1', 'T14d.r2', 'T14d.r3')), (('Sham1.r1', 'Sham1.r2', 'Sham1.r3'), ('T90d.r1', 'T90d.r2', 'T90d.r3')), (('Sham2.r1', 'Sham2.r2', 'Sham2.r3'), ('T14d.r1', 'T14d.r2', 'T14d.r3')),  (('Sham2.r1', 'Sham2.r2', 'Sham2.r3'), ('T90d.r1', 'T90d.r2', 'T90d.r3'))
```

---

The dput of what I want is:

```
list(list(c("Sham1.r1", "Sham1.r2", "Sham1.r3"), c("T14d.r1", 
"T14d.r2", "T14d.r3")), list(c("Sham1.r1", "Sham1.r2", "Sham1.r3"
), c("T90d.r1", "T90d.r2", "T90d.r3")), list(c("Sham2.r1", "Sham2.r2", 
"Sham2.r3"), c("T14d.r1", "T14d.r2", "T14d.r3")), list(c("Sham2.r1", 
"Sham2.r2", "Sham2.r3"), c("T90d.r1", "T90d.r2", "T90d.r3")))
```

Comment: What about `shams <- c(sham1, sham2); measurements <- c(day14, day90); expand.grid(shams, measurements)` or `strsplit(pairwise_combinations, " ")`?

Comment: @lukA I just saw I made a mistake in the question. With expand.grid() you get `(sham1.r1, T14d.r1), (sham1.r1, T14d.r2), etc`. I actually want `((sham1.r1, sham1.r2, sham1.r3), (T14d.r1, T14d.r2, T14d.r3)), ((sham1.r1, sham1.r2, sham1.r3), (T90d.r1, T90d.r2, T90d.r3)), etc`

Comment: You need to clarify the expected output. In which way is "the following" "a list of pairwise vectors". Please `dput` the desired results.

Comment: @Henrik I added the dput of the desired result

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
apply(expand.grid(shams, measurements), 1, unname)
```